# Add full website link in my html table, when I only add address of token in it ( resolved)

Tags: php, html

I have the following code in html table

```
<td style="color:#EFE1CE"><?php echo $checkSqlRow["ADDRESS"]; ?></td>
```

In this table I have different cryptocurrency (bsc/btc/pologon eg.) and on each one I have different tokens.
In this column ["ADDRESS"] I want to display the address of any each token, (I got it working)
But how can can I do the following.
If I add a address for bscscan.com,(xo3efe..............) and I click on the address it must open the address in bscscan or ethscan websites.
Is this possible, any sample on this will help me to understand how it is working

So if I put in  0x0f6f69b5bfcc8140084f484f063177ee91e13809, then when I click on it, it must open like this h@@ps://bscscan.com/token/0x0f6f69b5bfcc8140084f484f063177ee91e13809

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the anchor tag, like this -

```html
<td style="color:#EFE1CE">
<a href='https://bcscan.com/token/<?php echo $checkSqlRow["ADDRESS"]; ?>'>Name Of Currency</a></td>
```

Name Of Currency is whatever you want to appear in the cell.  `href` declares the link to go to when clicked.

Comment: Hi @Rohit   Thank you, I did try it, but in my php on that column with this td, I have about 54 tokens from coinmarketcup alone, so if I change it to what you give me, it shows the same info for all of them in my html table.

Comment: The rest of the value after token is upto you. I  have shown you the method.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you got it to work with help from Rohit, did just add second part

```
<a href="https://bscscan.com/token/<?php echo $checkSqlRow["ADDRESS"]; ?>">
                                <?php echo $checkSqlRow["ADDRESS"]; ?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).